# Insert mysql command to MS Access

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ms-access

I want to ask that how to insert data from vb.net to data store MS.Access. but always shows error INSERT INTO Statement.
this my code:

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO TbCustomers(Pro_ID, Swi_ID, Odf_ID, Bra_ID, Cus_ID, ServiceID, CustomerName, Phone, Address, Username, Password, IP, SwitchPort, Status, Description) VALUES(" & produc_ID & "," & Swi_id & "," & odf_id & "," & Bra_id & ",'" & CustomerID & "','" & serviceId & "','" & cName & "','" & cPhone & "','" & cAddress & "','" & username & "','" & password & "','" & IP & "','" & SwitchPort & "','yes','" & description & "')"

cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I can't find wrong statement.
I need some help.
Thanks

Comment: What error is showing?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please format your code by highlighting it and pressing Command/Control + K on your keyboard, or by indenting 4 spaces.

Comment: Please tell US the error you get and also try working with command Parameters. This is much more easier and safer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is Password, which is a reserved word.

Use [Password] in your SQL sentence.